# NSMutableArray sort custom object using selector

Tags: iphone, sorting, ios4, nsmutablearray

```
@interface PlayerVO : NSObject {
NSString *name;
int duration;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (readwrite) int duration;

@end
```

custom object to be sorted based on the value of duration (Ascending)

in another class, I created a function,

```
- (NSComparisonResult)sort:(PlayerVO *)otherObject {
if ([self duration] < [otherObject duration]) {
    return NSOrderedAscending;
} else if([self duration] > [otherObject duration]){
    return NSOrderedDescending;
} else {
    return NSOrderedSame;
}
}
```

Calling function

```
[data sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(sort:)];
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `sortedArrayUsingSelector:`, the selector you provide will be sent to the objects in the array. So your `-sort:` method needs to be declared and defined on the class of the objects that you are sorting, not on another class.